# Pause button doesn't work everytime

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a problem with the pause functionality in selenium IDE.
During my script, when I click in the pause button it doesn't have any effect. I have to click many times until it has an effect on the script.
Is there a timeout or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

hello you have to use pause command in selenium ide

```
  Command | Target |  value     
  Pause   | 15000  |
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: Do you know maybe workaround for a pause command? I've tried this but selenium just passing through it without any delay.